# issue with urlencoding edit patient

Tags: php, parsing, urlencode

I made a page called display Patient which has a table that will display all the patients' information from the database when the `view_all` option is clicked.

I wish to make an extra row that will allow users to click edit and it will edit information for that specific row.

I currently have not came up with how to make the `edit_patient.php` to take in all the values yet though.

I tried using

```
echo     "<td>". ?><a href="edit_patient.php?id=<?php echo
urlencode($patients["id"]) .?>">Edit</a>  "</td>"
```

but it doesnt work and shows an `error of unexpected ';'.`

display Patient

```
  <?php require_once("includes/session.php"); ?>
    <?php require_once("includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
    <?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
    <?php $layout_context = "admin"; ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <style>
            table {border:3px solid black; border-collapse:collapse; margin: 0 auto;}
            tr { background-color:white;}
            th {font-size: 20px;}
            td {font-size: 18px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;}
            input {border-radius: 4px; border-color: black; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom:10px;}
            h2 {margin-left:6%;}

            </style>

    </head>


    <body>

    <h2>View Patient Records</h2>


    <body>
    <form action="display_patient.php" method="post">
    <p>Select:
    <select name="patient_var" >
    <?php 
    $value = array(view_all, last_name, address); 
    foreach ($value as $option)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$option.'"' . (isset($_POST['patient_var']) && $_POST['patient_var'] == $option ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $option . '</option>';
    }

    ?>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="typed" value="" />

    <input type ="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    </p>

    <p>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['patient_var'])) {

        $type = $_POST['typed'];
        $select = $_POST['patient_var'];
     if ($select == 'view_all') {
         echo "<table border='1'>"; 
     echo "<tr>\n"; 
    echo "<th>ID</th>\n"; 
    echo "<th>First Name</th>\n"; 
    echo "<th>Last Name</th>\n"; 
    echo "<th>Age</th>\n";
    echo "<th>NRIC</th>\n";
    echo "<th>Birth Date</th>\n";
    echo "<th>Medical Allergies</th>\n";
    echo "<th>Medical History</th>\n";
    echo "<th>Phone</th>\n";
    echo "<th>Address</th>\n";
    echo "<th>Doctor Assigned</th>\n";
     echo "</tr>"; 

        $pat_set = default_patient();

         while ($mo = mysqli_fetch_array($pat_set)) {
                    echo "<tr>"; 
     echo "<td>" . $mo['id'] . "</td>"; 
     echo "<td>". $mo['first_name'] . "</td>"; 
     echo "<td>". $mo['last_name'] . "</td>"; 
      echo "<td>". $mo['age'] . "</td>"; 
       echo "<td>". $mo['nric'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td>". $mo['birthdate'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>". $mo['medical_allergies'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>". $mo['medical_history'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>". $mo['phone'] . "</td>";     
     echo "<td>". $mo['address'] ."</td>"; 
            echo "<td>". $mo['doctor_assigned'] . "</td>";
echo '<td><a href="edit_patient.php?id='.urlencode($mo["id"]).'">Edit</a></td>';
     echo "</tr>"; 
                }
     } 




    else {
        echo "<table border='1'>\n"; 
    echo "<tr>\n"; 
    echo "<th>ID</th>\n"; 
    echo "<th>First Name</th>\n"; 
    echo "<th>Last Name</th>\n"; 
    echo "<th>Age</th>\n";
    echo "<th>NRIC</th>\n";
    echo "<th>Birth Date</th>\n";
    echo "<th>Medical Allergies</th>\n";
    echo "<th>Medical History</th>\n";
    echo "<th>Phone</th>\n";
    echo "<th>Address</th>\n";
    echo "<th>Doctor Assigned</th>\n";
     echo "</tr>";

      $patients_set = 
     find_patients($select, $type);

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($patients_set)) 
     { echo "<tr>"; 
     echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>"; 
     echo "<td>". $row['first_name'] . "</td>"; 
     echo "<td>". $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>". $row['age'] . "</td>"; 
       echo "<td>". $row['nric'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td>". $row['birthdate'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>". $row['medical_allergies'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>". $row['medical_history'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>". $row['phone'] . "</td>";     
     echo "<td>". $row['address'] ."</td>"; 
            echo "<td>". $row['doctor_assigned'] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>"; }

    }  

    }//end of if post submit

    ?>
    </p>

    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

functions

```
  function default_patient(){
    global $connection;

    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "From patients ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY id ASC";
    $pat_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    confirm_query($pat_set);
    return $pat_set;


  }


function find_patients($select, $type) {
    global $connection;

    $safe_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $type);
    $safe_select = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $select);

    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM patients ";
    $query .= "WHERE {$safe_select} LIKE '%".$safe_type."%' ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY id ASC";
    $patients_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);  

    confirm_query($patients_set);
    return $patients_set;
  }
```

edit_patient

```
<?php require_once("includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/validation_function.php"); ?>
<?php find_selected_page(); ?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Process the form

//validations
$required_fields = array("first_name", "last_name", "postalcode", "nric", "address", "phone", "doctor");
validate_presences($required_fields);

$fields_with_max_lengths = array("phone" => 8);
validate_max_lengths($fields_with_max_lengths);


if( verify_nric($_POST['nric'])) {
$errors[] = 'This NRIC exists already.';    
}


if( !isValid( 'phone', $_POST['phone'] ) ) {
$errors[] = 'Please enter a valid phone number';       
}


if( !isValid( 'nric', $_POST['nric'] ) ) {
$errors[] = 'Please enter a valid nric number';       
}

if (empty($errors)) {
// perform Create
$d=$_POST['day'];
$m=$_POST['month'];
$y=$_POST['year'];

//converting Inputed DOB in "dd-mm-yyyy" format
$dob=$d.'-'.$m.'-'.$y;

//Create a new date object with current system date
$bday=new DateTime($dob);

//Differentiating both dates
$age=$bday->date_diff(new DateTime);

$today=date('d-m-Y');


$birthdate = mysql_prep($dob);
$c_age = $age->y; 


$name = mysql_prep($_POST["name"]);
$nric = mysql_prep($_POST["nric"]);
$allergy = mysql_prep($_POST["medical_allergy"]);
$history = mysql_prep($_POST["medical_history"]);
$phone = (int)$_POST["phone"];
$address = mysql_prep($_POST["address"]);
$doctor = mysql_prep($_POST["doctor"]);

//escape content


// 2. Perform database query

$query = "INSERT INTO patients (";
$query .= " name, age, nric, birthdate, medical_allergies, medical_history,
phone, address, doctor_assigned";
$query .= ") VALUES (";
$query .= " '{$name}', {$c_age}, '{$nric}', '{$birthdate}',
'{$allergy}', '{$history}', {$phone},  '{$address}', '{$doctor}'";
$query .= ")";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if ($result ) {
// Success
$_SESSION["message"] = "Record Updated.";


}else {
// Failure
$_SESSION["message"] = "Record creation failed.";
}   
}
} else {
// This is probably a GET request

} // End: If(isset($_POST['submit']))

?>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard - H H Lee & Associates Dental Surgery</title>
    <style>
        table {border:3px solid black; border-collapse:collapse; margin: 0 auto;}
        tr { background-color:white; }
        td { padding-left: 10px; }
        textarea{border-radius: 4px; border: 2px solid black; resize:none; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom:10px;}
        input {border-radius: 4px; border: 2px solid black; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom:10px;}
        h2 {margin-left:6%;}
        input[type=text]
        {
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
        input[type=submit]
        {
            padding: 5px 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #008080;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        input[type=submit]:hover
        {
            padding: 5px 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: #008080;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        #admin_back
        {
            margin-top: -15px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<?php $layout_context = "admin"; ?>



                        <?php echo message(); ?>
                        <?php echo form_errors($errors); ?>

                        <h2>EDIT A PATIENT RECORD</h2>

                        <form action="create_patient.php" style="text-align: left;
                              margin-left:6%;"method="post">

                            <table border='1' width='70%'>
                            <tr>
                               <td>ID of patient</td>
                               <td><input type="text" name="patient_id" value="" /></td>
                            </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>First Name:</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="first_name" value="" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="last_name" value="" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td> NRIC/ Foreign ID/ Passport:</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="nric" value="" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Date Of Birth:<br /></td>
                                    <td>Day<br/>
                                        <select name="day"> <!-- To Select Day -->
                                            <option value="01" selected="selected">01</option>
                                            <option value="02">02</option>
                                            <option value="03">03</option>
                                            <option value="04">04</option>
                                            <option value="05">05</option>
                                            <option value="06">06</option>
                                            <option value="07">07</option>
                                            <option value="08">08</option>
                                            <option value="09">09</option>
                                            <option value="10">10</option>
                                            <option value="11">11</option>
                                            <option value="12">12</option>
                                            <option value="13">13</option>
                                            <option value="14">14</option>
                                            <option value="15">15</option>
                                            <option value="16">16</option>
                                            <option value="17">17</option>
                                            <option value="18">18</option>
                                            <option value="19">19</option>
                                            <option value="20">20</option>
                                            <option value="21">21</option>
                                            <option value="22">22</option>
                                            <option value="23">23</option>
                                            <option value="24">24</option>
                                            <option value="25">25</option>
                                            <option value="26">26</option>
                                            <option value="27">27</option>
                                            <option value="28">28</option>
                                            <option value="29">29</option>
                                            <option value="30">30</option>
                                            <option value="31">31</option>
                                            <option value="32">32</option>
                                        </select>

                                        Month
                                        <select name="month"><!--TO Select Month-->
                                            <option value="01" selected="selected">Jan</option>
                                            <option value="02">Feb</option>
                                            <option value="03">Mar</option>
                                            <option value="04">Apr</option>
                                            <option value="05">May</option>
                                            <option value="06">Jun</option>
                                            <option value="07">Jul</option>
                                            <option value="08">Aug</option>
                                            <option value="09">Sep</option>
                                            <option value="10">Oct</option>
                                            <option value="11">Nov</option>
                                            <option value="12">Dec</option>
                                        </select>

                                        Year
                                        <select name="year"><!--To Select Year-->
                                            <option value="2013" selected="selected">2013</option>
                                            <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                            <option value="2011">2011</option>
                                            <option value="2010">2010</option>
                                            <option value="2009">2009</option>
                                            <option value="2008">2008</option>
                                            <option value="2007">2007</option>
                                            <option value="2006">2006</option>
                                            <option value="2005">2005</option>
                                            <option value="2004">2004</option>
                                            <option value="2003">2003</option>
                                            <option value="2002">2002</option>
                                            <option value="2001">2001</option>
                                            <option value="2000">2000</option>
                                            <option value="1999">1999</option>
                                            <option value="1998">1998</option>
                                            <option value="1997">1997</option>
                                            <option value="1996">1996</option>
                                            <option value="1995">1995</option>
                                            <option value="1994">1994</option>
                                            <option value="1993">1993</option>
                                            <option value="1992">1992</option>
                                            <option value="1991">1991</option>
                                            <option value="1990">1990</option>
                                            <option value="1989">1989</option>
                                            <option value="1988">1988</option>
                                            <option value="1987">1987</option>
                                            <option value="1986">1986</option>
                                            <option value="1985">1985</option>
                                            <option value="1984">1984</option>
                                            <option value="1983">1983</option>
                                            <option value="1982">1982</option>
                                            <option value="1981">1981</option>
                                            <option value="1980">1980</option>
                                            <option value="1979">1979</option>
                                            <option value="1978">1978</option>
                                            <option value="1977">1977</option>
                                            <option value="1976">1976</option>
                                            <option value="1975">1975</option>
                                            <option value="1974">1974</option>
                                            <option value="1973">1973</option>
                                            <option value="1972">1972</option>
                                            <option value="1971">1971</option>
                                            <option value="1970">1970</option>
                                            <option value="1969">1969</option>
                                            <option value="1968">1968</option>
                                            <option value="1967">1967</option>
                                            <option value="1966">1966</option>
                                            <option value="1965">1965</option>
                                            <option value="1964">1964</option>
                                            <option value="1963">1963</option>
                                            <option value="1962">1962</option>
                                            <option value="1961">1961</option>
                                            <option value="1960">1960</option>
                                            <option value="1959">1959</option>
                                            <option value="1958">1958</option>
                                            <option value="1957">1957</option>
                                            <option value="1956">1956</option>
                                            <option value="1955">1955</option>
                                            <option value="1954">1954</option>
                                            <option value="1953">1953</option>
                                            <option value="1952">1952</option>
                                            <option value="1951">1951</option>
                                            <option value="1950">1950</option>
                                            <option value="1949">1949</option>
                                            <option value="1948">1948</option>
                                            <option value="1947">1947</option>
                                            <option value="1946">1946</option>
                                            <option value="1945">1945</option>
                                            <option value="1944">1944</option>
                                            <option value="1943">1943</option>
                                            <option value="1942">1942</option>
                                            <option value="1941">1941</option>
                                            <option value="1940">1940</option>
                                            <option value="1939">1939</option>
                                            <option value="1938">1938</option>
                                            <option value="1937">1937</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td></tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Contact Number:</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="phone" value="" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Address:</td>   
                                    <td><textarea name="address" rows="3" cols="60" align="right"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Postal Code:</td>   
                                    <td><input type="text" name="postalcode" value="" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Dentist Assigned:</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="doctor" value="" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr><td>Medical Allergies:</td>
                                    <td><textarea name="medical_allergy" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea></p></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Medical History:</td>
                                    <td><textarea name="medical_history" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
                                        <a href="manage_content.php">Cancel</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your echo line is a little broken, and doesn't have a ;. Try this instead.

```
<?php
echo '<td><a href="edit_patient.php?id='.urlencode($patients["id"]).'">Edit</a></td>';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, i fixed it. Do you know how i can parse in the selected row's variables to the next page with that edit link?

Comment: I managed to parse in the variables to the next page. Thank you for your help =)

Comment: This should work :), it was just an issue with the single quotes not being escaped. <?php echo '<td><a href="delete_patient.php?id='.urlencode($mo["id"]).'" onClick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this patient?\');">Edit</a></td>'; ?>